# MVC 3 Insert string HTML code using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

the `preview` variable contains the HTML code. I want to display that code rendered, but is is being rendered as a raw text, why ?

```
 $("#pdf-dialog").dialog("option" , 'open' , function() { 
     @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(preview))
     {
         <text>
             $("#pdf-dialog").html("@preview");
         </text>
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`HtmlHelper.Raw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
@Html.Raw(preview)
```